# XCODE 8.1 when upgraded to 8.2, couldnt open, Not Responding

Tags: xcode

MAC OS 10.12.2 
XCODE 8.1 upgraded to 8.2
Restarted and opened But no response. Checked ForceQuit > list. Xcode is not responding. 
Any suggestion on recovering from this situation

Comment: Does the GUI open?  Can you click on anything?  Is your mouse frozen, or do you see the spinning beach ball?

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the similar issue and i think it's because during the update process when Xcode window was open and after the prompt message it kills the Xcode running instance and that probably corrupts the derived data. Try clearing the derived data and it should work as it does on my machine today.

Comment: Thanks for the reply
I have tried it. Cleaned but still not responding.